# Compiler's optimization techniques that replaces loops for formulas

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation

I'm aware that compilers (for example, clang and gcc), at least with all optimizations flags enabled, do semantic analysis of your loops to see if you are actually implementing some mathematical serie (e.g., sum of an arithmetic progression `1 + 2 + ... + n`), and the compiler completely removes the loop and replaces it with its corresponding formula (e.g., `n * (n - 1) / 2`).

Some months ago I found a *clang* or *llvm* documentation page about the different options and techniques use to find and apply these kind of optimization oportunities, but I'm not able to find it again.

So, the question is: what is the name of these kind of loop analysis optimization techniques and how are they actually applied?

Comment: Are you looking for loop unrolling and vectorization? Asking how they're applied is rather complex--check some offsite resources like wikipedia.

Comment: @ggorlen Nor loop unrolling neither vectorization does a completely removal of loops right?

Comment: Sure it can. It depends on how much you vectorize or unroll. If you have a loop that iterates 100 times you can turn it into 100 repetitions of the body operating on the explicit values the loop would yield without a branch. If the compiler can detect that there is an arithemetic progression, the compiler can make it O(1).